# What are the caches that get updated when re-compiling an oracle package?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, package, oracle12c

I am working with Oracle PL-SQL packages. There was a flow which seems to have an issue when executing and I was trying to figure it out. I did some data correction and still the issue was there. So I added traces and executed the flow again and there it worked perfectly!!!

It seems that the issue got fixed due to the re-compilation of the package. Is that possible? If so how this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities.

The more likely one is that your package stored some data in local variables such as PL/SQL collections. That would ignore data changes in the underlying source tables unless you had a procedure in place to trigger a repopulation. Compiling the package would wipe out the session state, so you would see the new data when you ran your procedure.

A variation on this would be storing the data in global temporary tables set at the transaction level. Again, recreating the package would issue a commit which would cause the GTT to discard the data.

An alternative possibility is that your procedure was running in a READ ONLY transaction. So it only saw the state of the data when the session started. Again, recompiling the package would break that.

---

If neither of these explanations applies to your situation you will need to provide more details about what your stored procedure was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Packages are collection of sub programs. When a sub program is called the first time, the entire package is loaded into Library Cache of Shared Pool. This is parsed and the code is then executed. For any subsequent calls, the parsed code is reused avoiding hard parsing. Earlier when the code was called first time, we get a library cache miss. The subsequent calls get a library cache hit.

If any object on which the package is dependent undergoes a structural change via a DDL, the parse code in the Library Cache is invalidated and is reloaded on the next invocation. I used to face this issue in nested procedures in Oracle 9i. Haven't faced this in 12c.

If you are interested in understanding the Oracle memory structures, the [OracleDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#GUID-1CB2BA23-4386-46DA-9146-5FE0E4599AC6) is the best place to start.